# FSharp Parameter Pattern matching. Why is declaration assigned from instead of to?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I am looking at FSharp.
Currently I am reading through this resource:
http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/

Since I am learning something completely new, including a new way of thinking, I am wary to just let something that makes little sense to me slide by.

```
let f1 name =                        // pass in single parameter   
    let {first=f; last=l} = name     // extract in body of function 
    printfn "first=%s; last=%s" f l
```

Why is the "f" and "l" on the **right** side of their respective "=" signs? Isn't this the point at which they are declared? I believe I know **what** the line does (it extracts the "first" and "last" properties from the "name" record). But I cannot understand the reasoning behind this syntactical choice, which leads me to suspect that I don't really understand the entirety of what's going on here.

Comment: Because it mirrors the syntax for creating a record.

Comment: The creation syntax (let {first="john"; last="Smith"}) makes sense. For the pattern matching, I would expect something like  "let {f=first; l=last} = name". I suspect I am going to be fighting my C# instincts on this one for some time. Thanks.

Comment: **Because it is not an assignment**. `let expr1 = expr2` denotes *binding*, e.g. `expr1` is attempted to pattern-match with `expr2`. If any of the expressions is a composite type, the matching continues recursively. In this case, `name` is a record, so `expr1` is **also** assumed to be a record, then the fields get pattern-mached, and then finally the compiler sees `f` and `l`, **yet unbound**, so it tries to bind them with the respective values. Again — to bind, not to assign.

Comment: That would make perfect sense to me if it was possible to execute "let 4 = x" (all by itself). As binding is not assignment, there is no reason why order would matter. The compiler would still be free to infer that the new symbol "x" needs to be of type int and basically follow the same "yet unbound" logic as you describe. But it **does** cause a compiler error. 
But even if it seems inconsistent (to me), I still feel your last comment helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of the syntax between `let` and `=` is called *pattern*. As mentioned in the comments, the pattern mirrors the syntax that you use when creating the record.

More generally, the idea with pattern is that you specify the part of objects that you know (here, the record field names) and in places that are varying (the values of the fields), you can either put a variable name (in which case pattern matching *binds* a variable)  or you can write `_` to ignore the value in that part of the object.

Here are some examples of creating values:

```
let opt = Some(42)                              // Option type containing int
let rcd = { First = "Tomas"; Last = "Hidden" }  // Record from your example
let tup = 42, "Hello"                           // Tuple with int and string
```

In all of the cases, you can mirror the syntax in a pattern:

```
let (Some(num)) = opt         // This gives warning, because 'opt' could also be None
let { First = n; Last = _ }   // Here, we explicitly ignore the last name using '_'
let _, str = tup              // Ignore first component of the tuple, but get the 2nd
```